# Rails for Zombie Level 5 Challenge 2 - Custom Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The objective is to create a custom route so that /undead will go to the undead action on the ZombiesController.

My code:

```
TwitterForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :zombies 
    match 'show_zombie' => "undead#show" 
end
```

And the error..."Did not add the correct route, could not get to ZombiesController#undead."

I'm not sure where i went wrong....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your route notation should look like this:

```
match 'path' => 'controller#action'
```

So, the path is undead, the controller is zombies, and the action is undead:

```
match 'undead' => 'zombies#undead'
```

Comment: in the video the match example is  

`match 'new_tweet' => "Tweets#new"`

My question is why `'zombies#undead'` instead of `'Zombies#undead'`

thank you in advance

Comment: According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), the convention is to express the controller in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

/undead goes to undead action

```
match 'undead' => 'zombies#undead'
```

You could replace `match` by one of `get, post, put, or delete`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is changed now, solution is :

RailsForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
match 'undead' => 'Zombies#undead'
end

Answer (score 0):

Read the objetive again :)

You want to get to ZombiesController#undead but you set it to go to ZombiesController#show